# Change color palette depending on variable in SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, variables, sass

I have multiple components in my react app using a top navbar, sidebar, cards, etc. All share the same color palette (assets/css/variables.scss):

```
$nav-color: #009788;
$side-color: #9be7db;
$side-color-selected: #84ebdb;
```

What I want to do is to change these three colors depending on a variable, for example, a boolean returned by the login. Is this posible to achieve in the variable.scss file?

Obviously, I want to keep the variables names cause all the components use these variables. I only want to change the variables values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it purely with Sass, because sass is pre-rendered to CSS, so any variables are resolved to a value by the time they are delivered to the browser.  **However**, you can point the Sass variables to [CSS Custom Properties (Variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and then update the value of the CSS variables with JS at your whim.  Below is an example with CSS only-- [but you can point Sass vars at CSS vars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66854088/6831341).

```js
document.querySelector('#toggleTheme')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    const themeVar = '--theme-color';
    const themeColor = document.body.style.getPropertyValue(themeVar);
    const newThemeColor = themeColor === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
    
    document.body.style.setProperty(themeVar, newThemeColor);
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --theme-color: red;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--theme-color);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button id="toggleTheme">Toggle Theme Color</button>
```

Comment: not exactly what I need. This app has about 100 components, all components import the variables.scss, and all of them uses these variables in their own styles.scss, thats why I need to change the values when, for example, the user is green or the user is blue.

Comment: @JavierOrellana7 - yes, but if the components are all importing the same Sass variables, and those three Sass variables are all pointing to three CSS variables, you should be able to programmatically change the CSS variables in the browser using JS and see all the importers that are pointing to those variables update in real time.  Or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: Imagine I have a Login and 20 modules after the auth. All of these modules have their own .scss that has classes. Ex: .some-class{ color: $nav-color}. Depending on the auth or whatever variable I need to change those three variables in the variables.scss file. Ex: user: blue (keep values), user: green (change the colors). What I'm asking is that there should be a way to do this (JS or scss) but I don't know how haha

Comment: @JavierOrellana7 - The way you are describing your scenario I don't see any reason this solution shouldn't work for you.  The CSS vars represent an abstraction that is alterable in the browser context, _after_ the Sass has been compiled.  If this is not the case, then I think you might need to update your question with more detail to provide enough context that visitors to the post can better understand the issue you are facing and help you solve it.